# Automatically overwriting .csv file from updated data frame?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I was wondering if there is any way to automatically overwrite a .csv file. Basically, I would have a user inputs something in the app, then my function would update the data table with that input and also let the user know that their input has been successfully received. However, I also want to update the base .csv that the dataframe reads on - so that would be a loop: we have a .csv file, dataframe reads it, the user inputs something in the app, the dataframe gets updated, and the .csv file would be updated also. I have this so far:

```
def submit_reviews(n_clicks, claims_list, verdict, category, review):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        return (dash.no_update, dash.no_update, dash.no_update, dash.no_update, dash.no_update)
    
    if n_clicks and claims_list and verdict and category and review:
        new_df["Reviewed_Indicator"] = new_df.apply(lambda row: verdict
                                                                  if row["Claim_Number"] in claims_list else row["Reviewed_Indicator"], axis = 1)
        new_df["Reviewed_Category"] = new_df.apply(lambda row: category
                                                                  if row["Claim_Number"] in claims_list else row["Reviewed_Category"], axis = 1)
        new_df["Reviewed_Reason"] = new_df.apply(lambda row: review 
                                                                  if row["Claim_Number"] in claims_list else row["Reviewed_Reason"], axis = 1)

        dcc.send_data_frame(new_df.to_csv, "results_test.csv", index=False)

        
        return ([], True, "success", "Thank you. Your review has been submitted.", 1)

    else:
        return (dash.no_update, True, 
                "danger", "Error submitting review. Please review your submission.", dash.no_update)
```

However, the send data frame action does not seem to run anyhow. Is it possible to that update in there?

Comment: if you want save on server then maybe directly `new_df.to_csv("results_test.csv", index=False)` ? BUT if you want to download by user on local computer then you have to `return dcc.send_data_frame(...)`. So it has to be last operation - and it can't return other elements - so maybe do it as separated button only for downloading.

Comment: You are correct that I should just use to_csv since I only need to save on the server, and get rid of the send_data_frame. However, it still does not update unfortunately.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see whjat you have in variables and which part of code is executed. Maybe it never goes to `if`. You could also check `Current Working Directory` - `os.getcwd()` because maybe it save it in different folder, or you should use `/full/path/to/results_test.csv`

Comment: Good idea. I tried put print('Test') right in front the return in the second if. The function is able to return the correct output (since when I tried to input from the app, it tells me that "Thank you. Your review has been submitted." However, it skips over the print('Test'). I will look further to see what's up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using pd.to_csv(path) already overwrites the files. You just have to make sure that the file is not in use.

Comment: I am pretty sure the file is not in use since it is a totally new file (results.csv versus results_test.csv). It does not show up still.

Comment: Maybe you should try to pass the file name as a raw input r"results_test.csv". Try it and let me know if there are any updates.